# Updates rejected in a git branch

Tags: git, github, version-control

I am contributing to a public repo. I cloned the repo and created a new branch `cmd_addons`. I wanted to commit a few changes after some days but my changes are getting rejected. These are the steps that I have followed:
(Assuming I am on the `cmd_addons` branch)

```
1. git pull upstream master && git push origin master
2. git add 'somefile'
3. git commit -m "..."
4. git push origin cmd_addons
```

This keeps throwing error `Updates were rejected because your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes`
After this I tried `git pull` but it says that everything is upto date.

PS: I already looked at [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915291/git-rejected-updates-pull-not-solving-it) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10298291/cannot-push-to-github-keeps-saying-need-merge). I am unable to understand what is the correct way of doing it without losing anything.

Comment: How did you create the `cmd_addons` branch?  Please include the steps.

Comment: `git pull origin cmd_addons` might be what you need to do here.

Comment: You're describing two *remotes* named `origin` and `upstream`. That implies there are three *repositories* involved, but you only mention two of them ("public repo" and "cloned"). I'm guessing here that there was an in-between step, "fork public repo to GitHub repo" (based on the github tag). We now need to know what you're doing with your `cmd_addons` branch in *your* repo (on your machine) and with the `cmd_addons` branch in the GitHub repo that you control (but that is not *your* repo).

Comment: In general, you cannot git push to repo unless repository owner granted you push permission (rare!). For GitHub repositories, usually you should create pull request - basically put your changes for review and ask repository owner to merge them.

Comment: `git pull origin cmd_addons` This worked. Thank you